# python crashed with Pyqt5 and QComboBox (QBasicTimer error)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

python crashed when I close program with this error :

**QBasicTimer::start: QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread**

I havn't Timer or Thread in my program.

And I discover the line which make crashing :

```
self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
```

or

```
comboBox = QComboBox(self)
```

or

```
comboBox = QComboBox()
self.myLayout.addWidget(comboBox)
```

In otherword, when I "draw" a QCombobox, there is the crash when I close the program

If I switch the QComboBox with another classic Widget (for example, QToolButton), there is no crash

I work with python 3 and pyqt5

I hope someone here can point out or guess why this is happening.